# How to show less text on a table using datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm using datatables jquery library to show some results from a Database.

```
var table =  jQuery('#table').DataTable({
    language: {
        searchPlaceholder: "Search Results",
    } ,
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]] ,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "ordering": true ,
});
```

But some data has long text, So the table exceeds the browser width.

I tried the following CSS:

```
#table td{
    word-break: break-all
}
```

But the length of the text increased and the height of the table too, Also one of the columns contain a URL which that property not working with.

So I need to use something like a readmore button.

Does datatables has that option? Or I should create that?

Comment: Can you pls add a snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/smjbvk6a/15/ , You need to use this library https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js which acquired jQuery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) callback to get the rendered cell and then you can do any DOM Manipulation that you want...

Here's an (not very semantic but working) example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    language: {
      searchPlaceholder: "Search Results",
    },
    "lengthMenu": [
      [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
      [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
    ],
    "autoWidth": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "ordering": true,
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [1, 4],
      createdCell: function(cell) {
        var $cell = $(cell);


        $(cell).contents().wrapAll("<div class='content'></div>");
        var $content = $cell.find(".content");

        $(cell).append($("<button>Read more</button>"));
        $btn = $(cell).find("button");

        $content.css({
          "height": "50px",
          "overflow": "hidden"
        })
        $cell.data("isLess", true);

        $btn.click(function() {
          var isLess = $cell.data("isLess");
          $content.css("height", isLess ? "auto" : "50px")
          $(this).text(isLess ? "Read less" : "Read more")
          $cell.data("isLess", !isLess)
        })
      }
    }]
  });

  //Moving Table Filtering Search Bar To A Table Header.
  $('#tableSearch').html($('.dataTables_filter'));
  //Moving Results Per Page DropDown Menu To A Table Header.
  $('#tablePerPage').html($('#table_length'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="display table table-hover table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headContainer">
      <th colspan="3">
        <div id="tablePerPage"></div>
      </th>
      <th colspan="4">
        <div id="tableSearch"></div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secondHeader">
      <th>#</th>
      <th class="rowHeader">Title</th>
      <th class="rowHeader">Image</th>
      <th class="rowHeader">Website</th>
      <th class="rowHeader">Description</th>
      <th class="rowHeader">Date</th>
      <th class="rowHeader">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableContent">
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td id="post_id">1</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</td>
      <td>https://placehold.it/300/300</td>
      <td> <a href="" target="_blank">http://website.com</a> </td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis possimus maiores, culpa sequi officiis nisi deserunt ratione voluptatem quasi, repellendus reiciendis obcaecati voluptatibus placeat qui quidem sint ex odit impedit!</td>
      <td>09-07-2018</td>
      <td>
        <button id="editPost" class="tableAction editPost btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editData" data-id="1">Edit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>

        <button id="deletePost" data-id="1" class="tableAction deleteDist btn btn-danger">Delete <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Btw, There's also a ellipsis renderer plugin [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26) but it doesn't have show/hide fuctionality

Comment: It's working, But not with links, Also sometimes the data is equal or less that the text that should be hidden and the readmore is shown for them

Comment: I added column '2' which is an image URL, The full link is shown and the readmore is beneath the URL not hiding or showing anything

Comment: You'll have to check manually if read more is required or not by checking the initial height... If initial height < 50 then read more is not needed

Comment: The link must have been shown because it's height is less than < 50px. You can also try truncating the text inside also `<a>`

Comment: Also I have just shown you a method of using `createdCell` you'll have to write code accordingly to the behaviour you want

Comment: I have already changes the button to `<a>`, Also I tried the ellipsis and it's great, 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Devansh J's solution I made some improvements. The button is only visible, if a specific size of linebreakes are existing.  Its not that precise as the cell-height, but were not able to find another solution. - hence on responsive tables the initial height is 0px (CSS flex). [Live Demo](http://live.datatables.net/zewaboxi/1/edit).

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      columnDefs: [
{
                    targets: "_all",
                            createdCell: function(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                                //https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242920/14226613
                                //https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/58336/how-to-know-the-height-of-a-cell
                                var $cell = $(cell)
                                if (cellData != null) {
                                    var linebreakes = cellData.split(/\r\n|\r|\n|br/).length
                                } else {
                                    var linebreakes = ''
                                }
                                //some debug
                                /*console.log("###cell:")
                                console.log($cell)
                                console.log("###amount line breakes: " + linebreakes)*/
                                
                                //jquery wrap a new class around the html structure
                                $(cell).contents().wrapAll("<div class='content'></div>");
                                //get the new class
                                var $content = $cell.find(".content");
                                //if there are more line as 12
                                if (linebreakes > 2) {
                                    //change class and reduce height
                                    $content.css({
                                        "height": "20px",
                                        "overflow": "hidden"
                                    })
                                    //add button only for this long cells
                                    $(cell).append($("<button>&#8650;&#x21CA;</button>"));
                                }
                                //get IF of this new button
                                $btn = $(cell).find("button");  
                                //store flag
                                $cell.data("isLess", true);
                                //eval click on button
                                $btn.click(function() {
                                  //create local variable and assign prev. stored flag
                                  var isLess = $cell.data("isLess");
                                  //ternary check if this flag is set and manipulte/reverse button
                                  $content.css("height", isLess ? "auto" : "20px")
                                  $(this).text(isLess ? '\u21C8 \u21C8' : '\u21CA \u21CA')
                                  //invert flag
                                  $cell.data("isLess", !isLess)
                                })
                          }
                    }
          
        ]
    });
})
```

CSS:

```
table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody td button {
  background-color: #77f772;
  padding: 1px 3px 1px 3px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1.0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.5px solid #808080;
  font-size: 90%;
  outline: none;
}
```