# Read More Buttons for Long Text in R Shiny DT Datatables

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I would like to include "read more" and "read less" buttons in my R Shiny DT datatables for cells with overflow / long text.

[This wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242920/4892627) by Devansh J demonstrates this functionality in a pure CSS / javascript datatable. You can click the "run code snippet" button to see it in action.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble achieving the same result in a shiny app. I've also reviewed other answers, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70996172/how-can-i-add-read-more-and-read-less-functionality-for-long-text-in-r-shiny) and [2](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp), but they don't get me any closer to a solution for datatables in the shiny context. Hopefully, Yihui can step in and save the day!

Here is a MWE that would benefit from text overflow buttons.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinipsum)

text_df = data.frame(
  numbers = 1:3,
  letters = LETTERS[1:3],
  text = c("Lorem", substr(shinipsum::lorem, 1, 100), substr(shinipsum::lorem, 1, 5000))
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("text_table")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$text_table = renderDataTable({
     datatable(text_df)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed very cool. No need of Shiny.

```r
library(DT)
library(shinipsum)

text_df <- data.frame(
  numbers = 1:3,
  letters = LETTERS[1:3],
  text    = c(
    "Lorem", 
    substr(shinipsum::lorem, 1, 100), 
    substr(shinipsum::lorem, 1, 5000)
  )
)

js <- "
function(cell) {
  var $cell = $(cell);
  $cell.contents().wrapAll('<div class=\\\"content\\\"></div>');
  var $content = $cell.find('.content');
  $cell.append($('<button>Read more</button>'));
  $btn = $cell.find('button');
  $content.css({
    height: '50px',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  });
  $cell.data('isLess', true);
  $btn.click(function () {
    var isLess = $cell.data('isLess');
    $content.css('height', isLess ? 'auto' : '50px');
    $(this).text(isLess ? 'Read less' : 'Read more');
    $cell.data('isLess', !isLess);
  });
}
"
datatable(
  text_df,
  rownames = FALSE,
  options = list(
    "columnDefs" = list(
      list(
        "targets" = 2,
        "createdCell" = JS(js)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

You can use a function with five arguments in `createdCell`:

```js
function(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, cellIndex) {
```

Then you can do for example `if(rowIndex > 0)` to skip the first row, or `if(cellData.length > 100)` to target cells with more than 100 characters.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Do you think it might be possible to make it only apply to specific cells in the column? For example, it might be nice to only see the "Read more" buttons on the cells with a lot of content. Or, is it only possible to apply it to the entire column. Perhaps there is a way to preselect the target cells.

Comment: To follow up, is there any reason why adding a conditional statement such as: ```  if($cell.data.length > 100){...}``` into the function doesn't work?